# Discord.js splitting the message at a certain point

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a lyrics command. Because of discord limit I have to split the message into parts. My current solution just splits the message at 2000 characters.

```
        for(let i = 0; i < besedilo.length; i += 2000) {

         const lyrics = new RichEmbed() 
        .setTitle(` ${serverQueue.songs[0].title} `)
        .setColor(0xFF1E24)
        .setAuthor('KSoft.Si', 'https://cdn.ksoft.si/images/Logo1024.png', 'https://ksoft.si/')
        .setDescription(`**Besedilo : **
        ${besedilo.substring(i, Math.min(besedilo.length, i + 2000))}
        `)
        .setFooter('Če besedilo ni pravo pač pride tako leto...\nZa izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');
        message.channel.send(lyrics).then(d_msg => { d_msg.delete(240000); });
        }

        }
```

Im looking to split it at the end of the verse

This is an example of a verse and it ends with \n\n.

```
I wanna be a billionaire so fucking bad\n
Buy all of the things I never had\n
I wanna be on the cover of Forbes magazine\n
Smiling next to Oprah and the Queen\n\n
```

Is there any way to split the message at the end of the verse and start the next message from the beggining of the verse?

Comment: Does a verse always end with a double newline (`\n\n`)?

Comment: Yes it always end with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is my suggestion, to be tested but should work.

```js
// Raw lyrics text
let originalLyricsText = "Lyrics...";
// This will produce an array of all verses.
let originalLyricsSplitted = originalLyricsText.split('\n\n');

// Intitializing first element with an empty string is important here.
let lyricsTextsToSend = [""];
// This represent the index of "lyricsTextsToSend" array we will fill with verses.
let i = 0;

// For each verses we will fill our messages content.
originalLyricsSplitted.forEach(verse => {
    // Adding "\n\n" at the end of the current verse else there wouldn't be any space between verses in messages. 
    verse += "\n\n";

    // Checking that if we add the verse we don't goes upper the message limit.
    if (lyricsTextsToSend[i].length + verse.length < 2000) {
        // We don't go upper so concatenating the current verse in the current message content.
        lyricsTextsToSend[i] += verse;
    } else {
        // We go upper the limit, we switch to a new message and filling it with the current verse.
        i++;
        lyricsTextsToSend[i] = verse;
    }

    // Looping until we have added all verses.
});

// From here, lyricsTextsToSend will contain each messages strings you will have to send.
// You can now create kind of a queue of embeds to send by pushing Promises in an Array.
let messageQueue = [];
lyricsTextsToSend.forEach(messageString => {
  let lyricsEmbed = new RichEmbed() 
  .setTitle(` ${serverQueue.songs[0].title} `)
  .setColor(0xFF1E24)
  .setAuthor('KSoft.Si', 'https://cdn.ksoft.si/images/Logo1024.png', 'https://ksoft.si/')
  .setDescription(`**Besedilo : **
    messageString`)
  .setFooter('Če besedilo ni pravo pač pride tako leto...\nZa izboljšavo pišite predloge na: Anej#0001');

    messageQueue.push(message.channel.send(lyricsEmbed));
});

// All messages are build and ready to be send in order.
// To do this we will use Promise.all method that will process each Promises in order.
Promise.all(messageQueue).then(messages => {
    // All messages are sent, we now need to add the delete timeout on each messages sent.
    messages.forEach(message => {
        message.delete(240000);
    });
});

// Done!
```

Comment: Edited my answer, I forgot to put the actual `messageString` in the embed description.

Comment: Cool, that's roughly the same as what I was going to say

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered but I'm going to put my solution in anyway in case you find it helpful:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const testbot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'NzA2NTkyNzgwMTAwNjk4MTYz.XsUZmQ.am52L1QKlP_wNwneyClRUmr_uWA'; //put token here

var msg = 'helloo\nthere\n\n\nmy fine friend' //<-lyrics go there. separate individual lines with \n and verses with \n\n\n.
var foo = '';
var limit = 2000;
var size = 0;
var max = 0;



testbot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('bot is online');
})

testbot.on('message', message=>{  //obviously you can add your own event here
    if(message.author.bot) return 0; //you only need this if message is your event
    let verse = msg.split('\n\n'); //this also removes the two \ns from the string so another is required.
    console.log(verse.length);
    for(var i = 0; i<verse.length; i++){
        size = verse[i].length;
        max = limit - size;
        if(foo.length < max){ //do 1400 to ensure that next verse does not break the limit. Change this as you please.
            foo = foo + '\n' + verse[i]; //to put a space between verses.
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send(foo); //send if message is too big
            foo = verse[i];
        }
    }
    message.channel.send(foo);

})

testbot.login(token);
```

Comment: Would't this just error when it would hit the limit? And im not trying to send a verse per embed Im trying to send as little as possible. And im still using an old version.

Comment: well you could just do 'message.channel.send(verse[0]);' and then do 'message.channel.send(verse[1]);' or whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: And, no, I don't think it will trigger the limit.

Comment: There are multiple verses, more than 2 so to send the entire lyrics I would have send a lot of embeds. I want to send 2 or 3 embeds at most. Im just trying to split the message at the limit preserving the last verse in the embed and then start a new embed at the beggining of a verse.

Comment: Ok I think I have a solution lemme just see if it works